# fancontrol (pwmconfig) won't detect my fans

Tags: 16.04, graphics, hardware, fan, fancontrol

My laptop's CPU fan creeps me out and I am trying to lower it but when I am attempting to run `sudo pwmconfig` and I get `/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed`

The laptop is an HP G250 G5, with Intel i3 CPU, and AMD R5 M430, but the driver doesn't exist for Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: pwmconfig finds that your system doesn't have any pwm fans. Pretty clear. Uninstall pwmconfig. You'll have to clarify what "my laptop's CPU fan creeps me out" means. Are you saying they run too much, or not enough? Is your laptop overheating?

Comment: @heynnema they run too much, and the CPU temperature most of the time is 40-46*C

Comment: 40-46C isn't too hot. In `terminal` type `dpkg -l intel-microcode | grep ii` and then `dpkg -l thermald | grep ii` and show me the results. Edit the results (if you get any) into your original question, not in the comments please... unless there's no result. How old is this laptop?

Comment: @heynnema I'll check it out and let you know. I bought the laptop 4 months ago or so. And about the temperature, i know it isn't that hot but the noise it's annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you're running BIOS `F.23 Rev.A` from Dec 23, 2016. If you need to update, go to https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-250-g5-notebook-pc/10180321.

In `terminal`...

```
dpkg -l intel-microcode | grep ii
```

If it returns no result, then...

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install intel-microcode
reboot
```

In `terminal`...

```
dpkg -l thermald | grep ii
```

If it returns no result, then...

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install thermald
reboot
```

You'll want to read up a little on `thermald` by typing `man thermald` and `man thermal-conf.xml`, in `terminal`. After stopping the currently running thermald process, you can run `thermald` manually in `--no-daemon mode` to watch if it's doing the right thing, or as a basis for writing your own custom config file.

Comment: My BIOS version is F.21, but I don't see Linux drivers to select, is there a problem if I select Windows 10 64-Bit and download the bios from this section? Besides this, the installer is an .exe, and I have some troubles with Wine, I can't install it properly

Comment: Don't try install the BIOS update using WINE. Use a standard Windows system.

Comment: Bit hard to install BIOS update if you have no windows installed - any other method?